# Set a type for an object but infer it's actual type from its value

Tags: typescript

I'm currently working on a multistep form. I want to construct objects for each step, that contains the name of the fields and whether they are required.

```
type Form = {
  firstName: string
  lastName: string
  streetAddress: string
  streetNumber: string
};

type Field = {
  required: boolean
  label: string
}

// Currently this type enforces each of my steps to include ALL fields from my form. 
// Simply wrapping the fields type in Partial<> doesn't give me the type I wish for.
type Step<T extends keyof Form = keyof Form> = {
  fields: Record<T, Field>
  // ... I have more properties here
}

// This gives me an error as I haven't defined streetAddress and streetNumber
const Step1: Step = {
  fields: {
    firstName: {
      required: true,
      label: "First name"
    },
    lastName: {
      required: true,
      label: "Last name"
    },
  }
}

// This gives me an error as I haven't defined firstName and lastName
const Step2: Step = {
  fields: {
    streetAddress: {
      required: false,
      label: "Street Address"
    },
    streetNumber: {
      required: false,
      label: "Street number"
    },
  }
}


// Should give TS error as firstName is not defined in Step2
Step2.fields.firstName


// Should not give TS error as streetAddress is defined in Step2
Step2.fields.streetAddress

// Wrapping fields in partial, e.g. fields: Partial<Record<T, Field>>
// Will cause all my types to be possibly undefined
```

All in all my issue is that I want the objects that I create to live up to a certain interface, but have their type inferred by their value. E.g. If I to create the `Step1` object without specifying that it's of type `Step`, it would let me know that only `Step1.fields.firstName`, and `Step1.fields.lastName` exists on it.

https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-forked-97f3t?file=/src/index.ts

Comment: Try wrap `Record` in a `Partial`. `fields: Partial<Record<T, Field>>;`

Comment: Also, could you please provide an example of expected and unexpected behavior. It is not clear enough for me what you want to achieve

Comment: @kaya3 not quite. I want to be able to specify the type and not solely having it inferred from a function call. Following your example, I can't see how I would do the type declaration for the fields object in the Step type.

Comment: @captain-yossarian I've updated the code with a few lines of comment, hope that clarifies what I want to achieve.

Comment: YOu need to use extra function, just like @kaya3 wrote